# jquery php load when user enters room

Tags: php, jquery, setinterval

I am developing a multiplayer board game. which user enters an empty room, and waits for someone else to join so they can start playing.
the issue im facing is, when the first play joins the empty room. the room is empty, and his name is being displayed as Michael. when second player(Peter) joins the room from another browser Michael will be listed as Player1 and he as player2. but how can I make the browser of Michael of display (Peter has joined the room) . Im thinking of using jquery setInterval, but I dont find this efficient since it is consistently calling the server. Any suggestions?
example: Michael goes to www.board.com/game=1  and waits for someone to join
Peter goes to www.board.com/game=1 and he joins. in Peters browser he can see Micael in the room. But in MICHAELS browser he cannot see. how can I make michael notified if someone has joined the room?  is jQuery setinterval the solution only? isnt it un-efficient?

Answer (score 2):

you could open up a web socket from the browser...

http://www.websocket.org/

but otherwise, you would have to regularily poll the server to get updated data..i would set up a php file to deliver a json blob with your interface changes (game/chat data only) then using jquery, setup an ajax call to that php file to go off every 10-20 seconds.  if youre just polling data, it wont take too many resources..

Comment: As I've made an online board game with the exact same problem (except the server part is in Go and not in PHP), I concur : WebSockets are very good for this. But I have no idea about to make websockets work with PHP.

Comment: if you agree you should bump me up! :)

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the HTTP is that you **can't** call the user's browser and you can not make it reload (or load info) from the server. Only the browser can access the content from the server whenever he wants. That why the only option (if you dont want to reload the page) is using jQuery and call the server using short intervals.

Comment: it wont be efficient. is this how yahoo game does? it keeps on checking with server?

Answer (score 0):

you could do a ajax request and make the same request again iside the callback if the result is not matching your needs, and maybe delay it with window.setTimeout("method()", 1000);

Comment: I think i have to use sockets in php.

Comment: you won't be able to change the site content without either reloading the page or using javascript ajax calls. with window.setTimeout you can decide if you want to do another interval each time you processed a result from server, so your interval doesn't execute again if you don't need it anymore

Comment: should do `window.setTimeout(function(){this.method();}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP wasn't made for this kind of situations but I have good news, internet has evolved and you can achieve realtime aplications in diffrent ways.
First, the newer, the better but less compatible HTML5 WebSockets.
Or with Ajax doing regular requests to update your page or using techniques like 'Comet programing' wich sends requests and leave them open until the server has a response.